TypeScript SetIterator.toArray() Method Not Recognized
Description:
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to use the toArray() method on a SetIterator object in TypeScript. While the method is available in JavaScript, TypeScript is flagging an error indicating that the method does not exist on the SetIterator type.
  const str1 = "abcd"
  const set1 = new Set([...str1]);

  let keys: SetIterator<string> = set1.keys();

  return keys.toArray().join("");
// get error Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'SetIterator<string>'.ts(2339)


Why typescript can't recognize toArray() method?
TypeScript version:
^5.7.0-dev.20241013
VScode: 1.94.2
vite: "^5.0.8"
--target : ES2020 (tsconfig.json // "target" : "ES2020")
I've tried using explicit type assertions, but they haven't resolved the issue.
I've verified that my TypeScript setup is up-to-date.
I've consulted relevant documentation and community forums without finding a solution.
i know about Array.from()

Does return [... keys].join(""); work?

still experimental?

@cmgchess i tried out the nightly build of TypeScript to see if this has already been fixed or not.

I'm not very fluent in Typescript; where does SetIterator come from? I can't find any mention of it searching around, or at typescriptlang.org so it's not clear what could be going on.

@Pointy yes its work but the main problem is, why TS complaining about there is not such method in set1.keys() Is there a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Is there a bug - I'm guessing there is a bug

Well if the .toArray() is still experimental in the JavaScript domain, then it does not seem unreasonable that Typescript has not yet extended some base declarations to reflect its presence. It's not a bug if they have deliberately chosen not to support a not-yet-standard JavaScript feature.

@Pointy set1.keys() return SetIterator

@ErfanTa great, but does the SetIterator or the base Iterator class have .toArray() in the declaration? If not, then you get that error from the Typescript transpiler because that property reference is undefined.

@Pointy The toArray() method is not experimental in JavaScript. It was added as part of the ES6 standard, which is now widely supported by modern browsers and JavaScript environments.

@JaromandaX i think it is .they dont add this yet

@Pointy SetIterator inherit  form Iterator and in Iterator 's prototype has method toArray

What's your --target? That method is not part of the current ES standard (it's not in ES6, which was almost 10 years ago. It looks like it will make it into ES2026 maybe? or ES2025 possibly?).  TS only supports it if your target is esnext as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz My apologies for any confusion., toArray() isn't part of ES6 Array.from() was introduced in ES6  I misspoke earlier clearing that up! Got it now, thank you.

And the rest of my comment and my question about targeting esnext? Does that clear up the issue for you or am I missing something?

@jcalz yes clearly you will go to tsconfig.json and change target to esnext

You've shared your vscode and vite versions, but neither are really relevant. However, as jcalz mentioned, we need your tsconfig to reproduce this issue - please [edit] your question to include it.

The Iterator Helpers proposal has recently reached Stage 4 of the TC39 process, so it will make it into the ECMAScript standard soon. TypeScript implemented typings for these in microsoft/TypeScript#58222 which was released with TypeScript 5.6. Because they are not part of any existing ES standard, if you want to use them in TypeScript you will need to set your --target compiler option to "ESNext", to get the latest typings. Once you do that, your code will compile as expected:
const str1 = "abcd"
const set1 = new Set([...str1]);

let keys: SetIterator<string> = set1.keys();

keys.toArray().join(""); // okay

Playground link to code
